Insufficient Access on Cross-Reference ID when doing Database.rollback
Working with some legacy code with a failing testmethod
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a10QL00001F5C5uYAF;
   first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, 
   insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 003QL00000ULy6d: []


the code under test sets a System.Savepoint, then does work including ..

insert a Contact (happens to match the cross-reference id 003QL00000ULy6d)


the code under test then throws a null pointer exception that is caught
and the catch block does a Database.rollback that deletes the inserted Contact

But the transaction fails with the DmlException as shown above.
There's plenty written about diagnosing this error including that one can get it when the referenced Id is deleted. But why would this block Database.rollback?

The joys of working on legacy code
Here's what is going on

A trigger on MyCustomObject__c is running in beforeSave context
MyCustomObject__c has a field Contact__c that is a lookup to Contact

This lookup field is defined to clear value if the parent record is deleted


The code under test created the Contact and put its Id into MyCustomObject__c.Contact__c so that it would be "saved" when the beforeSave trigger concluded.

So, I thought that when the Database.rollback(savePoint) was done and the inserted Contact was deleted, that Salesforce would remove (clear) the Id in the MyCustomObject__c.Contact__c.
But Salesforce will not clear the value in beforeSave context. Instead, beforeSave completes and Salesforce initiates the save sequence with a lookup field pointing at a deleted Contact. Hence the  INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error
Workaround
The workaround was to have the code under test register all lookup fields set during the beforeSave context and prior to execution of Database.rollback, to clear the registered lookup fields.
Pro Tip
Here's another reason why it is bad practice to do DML in the beforeSave context. Had the DML (i.e. insertion of Contact) been done in the afterSave context, then you have more control over when to update the MyCustomObject with lookup fields if you might be doing a Database.rollback in the transaction.
